# What is the alphabet for the following cipher?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I got this image with some strange drawings and I cannot figure out from which cipher it comes from. The only hint I got was "coca cola".

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_scripts

Comment: Actually, the clue _is_ helpful in identifying the script! Consider: Coca-Cola has its world headquarters in Atlanta, in the state of **Georgia**.

Comment: If this is not an original puzzle, please specify the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the [Modern Georgian Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_language#Writing_system), so the latinized version would be:

> kh n u l o r kh z

Not really helpful, right?